# A "random" question: usage of "random" as adjective in Spanish

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, españa, adjetivos, neologismos

In recent years I have been hearing people say in Spanish that something is *random*, but in contexts where it cannot be translated as "aleatorio" or "al azar" as usual.

Some examples:

> Es un tío muy *random*.

In this case I suppose its meaning could be that the guy is *caprichoso* or maybe *impredecible*. But then the other day I heard something like this in *La Voz* when a guy was about to start singing:

> Esto que siento es muy *random*.

Now the two adjectives I considered before do not fit in here. So I am trying to think of a Spanish word that can fit in both contexts (and maybe others) to see if there is really the need for this neologism, but I cannot come up with anything. I suppose the guy just did not understand what he was feeling so he used the *random* word in the sense of *inexplicable*.

So questions:

1. How is the word *random* used today in Spanish? Are there other contexts where it is being used?
2. Is it a proper neologism? Can it be substituted for a single Spanish word in every context? Or does it need to be substituted for different words depending on the context?
3. I have heard the word in Spain so I added the [españa](/questions/tagged/espa%c3%b1a) tag. Is it used also in Latin America with the same meaning?

Comment: I've noticed the same use of the word among young Engish speakers, which was confirmed by the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=random).

Answer (score 6):

No coincido con la respuesta de walen. Para mí, tal como lo entiendo, *random* significaría algo como

> que aparece espontáneamente en un contexto con el que no guarda ninguna relación lógica.

(me la acabo de inventar), pero creo que existe un acuerdo bastante general en que significa algo así. De hecho, *random* en inglés significa "aleatorio", y aleatorio significa, según la RAE

> **aleatorio, ria**
>
> 1. Perteneciente o relativo al juego de azar.
> 2. Que depende del azar.

Pero me gustaría ir algo más allá. Con una interpretación más científica o filosófica, el azar es **lo opuesto al determinismo**. Determinismo significa que existen leyes naturales o lógicas que rigen la evolución de la situación. De esta forma, conociendo la situación inicial, podemos **predecir** lo que va a ocurrir, porque existe un orden lógico que gobierna el desarrollo de los acontecimientos.

Por el contrario, el azar, o **aleatoriedad** implica que no se puede predecir lo que va a ocurrir. Tan solo se pueden estimar probabilidades, pero no existe certeza de lo que va a ocurrir.

Esto me lleva a pensar en *random* como algo `inesperado`, de ahí también lo de "sorprendente", como bien decís.

Ahora bien, discrepo de que tenga siempre connotaciones positivas. Hoy en día se pueden escuchar frases como

> Estábamos tan tranquilos y de repente empezó a gritar como un loco, así, *random*.

Esta frase es negativa, pero contiene el mismo significado de esta palabra: sin ninguna lógica, sin sentido, `porque sí`. De hecho, creo que la expresión "porque sí" es la que mejor lo describe. Quizás se puedan buscar adjetivos similares:

> Absurdo
>
> Incoherente
>
> Irracional

Le encuentro bastante relación con el **dadaísmo**, que vendría a consistir en "hacer arte con cosas *random* " (perdonad la simplificación ^^). Algunos de los adjetivos que los dadaístas utilizan para describirse a sí mismos son los que acabo de listar.

No obstante, creo que *random* tiene tintes propios. Personalmente no tendría problema en aceptarlo como neologismo, aunque es solamente una opinión.

Answer (score 2):

La palabra *"random"* usada en español no quiere decir nada en particular.

La cultura *millenial* americana considera lo impredecible, lo sorprendente y lo inesperado como algo bueno, algo que mola, algo *cool*. Para describir cosas con estas características, empezaron a usar la palabra ***"random"*** con carga positiva.

Un ejemplo de algo *"random"* sería [el último anuncio de Phoskitos para España](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNf9BMGezBk) o [el de Fanta con Rubius](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvkRXm_Yst8).

A la cultura *millenial* española ha llegado el término a través de *youtubers*, vídeos graciosos, series *teen* y demás contenido audiovisual en inglés en donde lo único que ven es que *"random"* se usa cada vez que pasa algo "guay". Y por tanto en España se usa esta palabra sin mucho criterio: sirve lo mismo para algo sorprendente, que para algo divertido, que para algo que sencillamente te genera un sentimiento positivo.

Fuente: experiencia propia a base de observar, con una mezcla de interés científico y desesperanza, el uso del lenguaje de mi hermano adolescente.

Comment: Veo que tu fuente es la misma que la mía (incluyendo lo de la desesperanza), solo que en mi caso los sujetos de estudio eran mis compañeros de trabajo.

Answer (score 2):

*Random* in Spanish is a colloquial and trendy way of saying *bizarro*, which, although not included in RAE, is usually used to mean "incoherent", and by thus, funny.

Take a look at this aricle: https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2015/11/05/articulo/1446740407_989364.html

In relation to this answer: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28995/21492, I must say "[...] un tío loco, así, *random*." is synonymous to "[...] un tio loco de la nada.".

Answer (score 0):

Yo no soy de españa pero aveces lo escucho aca, a mi me suena como si quisieran decir "bizarro". Onda, algo loco, absurdo, como las cosas que pasan en JoJo Bizarre adventures jajjaja.

Im not from spain but I hear it from time to time. Usually the meaning behind it is like "bizarre", not bizarre in terms of courage but bizarre in terms of something crazy, weird. It may have good or bad connotations depending on the context.

Comment: ¿dónde es "acá" para ti? Sería interesante que lo indicaras, para ampliar el conocimiento de lugares donde se usa. ¡Gracias y bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]!

Comment: Gracias! De Argentina. Algo que si es para notar, es que por estos lares el ingles no es un idioma tan comun donde vas y cualquiera entiende. Por eso si alguien usa la palabra "random", o es un "cheto" o alguien joven que de chico usa internet y consume entretenimiento en ingles.